# SQL Server table-valued function executed code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, row-level-security

Based on [Row level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security) I have created a table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Security.userAccessPredicate(@ValueId int)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT 1 AS accessResult
    WHERE @ValueId = 
    (
        SELECT Value 
        FROM dbo.Values 
        WHERE UserId = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserId') AS NVARCHAR(50))
    ) OR NULLIF(CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserId') AS nvarchar(50)),'') IS NULL
);

CREATE SECURITY POLICY Security.userSecurityPolicy
    ADD FILTER PREDICATE Security.userAccessPredicate(ValueUd) ON dbo.MainTable
```

Let's say `MainTable` contains milions of rows. Is `userAccessPredicate` calculating `SELECT Value FROM dbo.Values` for every row independently? If so it is ineffective I guess. How to check what exact code is generating when executing table-valued function? SQL Server Profiler isn't way because I am using Azure DB.

I am using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

Comment: The article you have linked, has a link to another article talking about performance: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/04/23/row-level-security-performance-and-common-patterns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to look at an execution plan with the policy turned off then turned on. You'll see the extra work its doing as a consequence. You're adding another table to query so its similar to doing a join but probably more efficient.

To answer your question, if you see the addition of a nested loop in the plan when the policy is on, then yes its going row-by-row [Nested Loops](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318(v=sql.105).aspx)

Also do the same with DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS to get a look at the resource hits too. With smaller tables i never saw any noticeable performance hits, < 100,000 rows in a similar implementation.

I found this link useful when getting into this before.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4005/sql-server-2016-row-level-security-limitations-performance-and-troubleshooting/